# Updating rows in a table using join and group by in Oracle produces an ORA-01732 error “data manipulation operation not legal on this view”

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-join

I need to update some rows in a table using join and group by statement. This is my SQL script:

```
update (select t1.name, t1.status as newStatus , count(table2.id) from table1 t1  
full outer join table2 t2  on (t1.id = t2.table1_id)
where t1.status = 'Old Status' 
group by t1.name, t1.status
having count(t2.id) = 0) res
set res.newStatus = 'New Status';
```

It seems that this is not possible because of "Group by" statement as I am getting the following error message:

> ORA-01732: "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"

Could anyone please help me finding another approach to do it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Neither `full join` nor `group by` make sense in an `update`.  It is quite unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be doing the count to determine that no matching rows appear in `table2`; in which case you can use `not exists` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html)) to determine that instead:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.status = 'New Status'
where t1.status = 'Old Status' 
and not exists (
  select *
  from table2 t2
  where t2.table1_id = t1.id
);
```

Your original statement used a full outer join which also didn't really make sense, as you need a `table1` row to update.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is exactly what i was trying to do. Your solution worked perfect for me.